# referencing image url in asset vendor directory

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, assets

How can I reference `background image url` when the css file is in `vendor/assets/stylesheets` directory ?  After looking to `SO` posts

```
background: url(myimage.png) repeat-x;
```

and

```
background: asset-url('myimage.png'image) repeat-x;
```

but none of them worked

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should try

```
background: url("/assets/ion/myimage.png") repeat-x;
```

Answer (score 0):

Place your image inside `app/vendor/assets/images/myimage.png`

```
#research_sign {
background: url("myimage.png") repeat-x;
}

    #Important: don't forget to restart your server!
     (as you added image inside your vendor/images)
```

Answer (score 0):

try this File Path

```
 background-image: url("../../assets/ion/myimage.png") repeat-x;
```